# How Can I Solve 'Notifications not accepted. You can turn them on later under your iOS settings' Issue?

Tags: swiftui, onesignal

I'm using onesignal for push notifications and it was working well until the ios 14 upgrade. When I build the same app without any changes on Xcode 12, I got this warning in the console.

> Notifications not accepted. You can turn them on later under your iOS
> settings

There was no problem on iOS 13, it happened when I update to iOS 14.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds
import OneSignal
import UserNotifications
import SDWebImageWebPCoder

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, OSPermissionObserver, OSSubscriptionObserver {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    var shortcutItemToProcess: UIApplicationShortcutItem?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        
        let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false, kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: false]
        
        OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                        appId: "my key is here",
                                        handleNotificationAction: nil,
                                        settings: onesignalInitSettings)
        OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications(userResponse: { accepted in
           print("User accepted notifications: \(accepted)")
         })
        
        // Add your AppDelegate as an obsserver
        OneSignal.add(self as OSPermissionObserver)
        
        OneSignal.add(self as OSSubscriptionObserver)
        
        registerForPushNotifications()
        
        let WebPCoder = SDImageWebPCoder.shared
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(WebPCoder)
        
        
        return true
    }
    
    
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.delegate = self
        
        let readAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "oku", title: "Haberi Oku", options: [.foreground])
        let closeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "kapat", title: "Kapat", options: [])
        
        let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "etkilesim", actions: [readAction, closeAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        
        notificationCenter.setNotificationCategories([category])
    }
    
    func onOSPermissionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSPermissionStateChanges!) {
        if stateChanges.from.status == OSNotificationPermission.notDetermined {
            if stateChanges.to.status == OSNotificationPermission.authorized {
                print("Thanks for accepting notifications!")
            } else if stateChanges.to.status == OSNotificationPermission.denied {
                print("Notifications not accepted. You can turn them on later under your iOS settings.")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onOSSubscriptionChanged(_ stateChanges: OSSubscriptionStateChanges!) {
        if !stateChanges.from.subscribed && stateChanges.to.subscribed {
            print("Subscribed for OneSignal push notifications!")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        
        // Grab a reference to the shortcutItem to use in the scene
        if let shortcutItem = options.shortcutItem {
            shortcutItemToProcess = shortcutItem
        }
        
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
    

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        var postId:String = ""
        var postType:String = ""
        
        if let custom = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["custom"] as? NSDictionary{
            if let a = custom["a"] as? NSDictionary{
                if let id = a["id"] as? String{
                    postId = id
                }
                if let type = a["rights"] as? String{
                    postType = type
                }
            }
        }
        
        if response.actionIdentifier == "oku" {
            if postId != ""{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Detail"), object: nil, userInfo: ["id": postId, "type": postType])
                })
                completionHandler()
            }
        }else if response.actionIdentifier == "kapat" {
            print("KAPAT")
            completionHandler()
        } else {
            if postId != ""{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("Detail"), object: nil, userInfo: ["id": postId, "type": postType])
                })
                completionHandler()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! :) If your app name contains non-English characters, change your Product Name under Build Settings and build it again, that's it :)

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHkYe.png)

Then you can change 'Bundle display name' in info.plist.

Comment: I was panicking because I had triple checked a production app, revoked, recreated push certificates... and this was the issue, a non-English character Product Name. Thank you for sharing this!